# What do we do with questions that are old and have no answers

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

It's one of those days where I'm in the mood for a spring clean-up on JSE.

Lets say there are some questions that are 6 months old, don't have any answers and don't have any upvotes. What action should be taken here?

At this point, I can only assume the OP has either gone with a different approach, therefore should we vote to close? flag to delete?

Opinions?

Comment: Great idea to have a spring cleanup sprint. You have my support in looking into flagged questions.

Comment: Cheers Valentin. Will start tomorrow

Comment: @ValentinDespa - Reached the "vote to close" limit.

Comment: how many can you vote to close? I think you can also flag the questions with " in need of moderator intervention" and refer to this question.

Comment: Yesterday I also reached "close limit" after 15 votes to close. Didn't know they have such a limit too... Oh, well...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that despite the question has received no attention (upvotes, comments, answers), if it is a good question, then we could upvote it and try to draw attention to it, or even answer it.

I believe we should not be closing good questions, even if they don't have answers or other activity already.
At some point, someone could post a really good answer so future users with a similar problem will arrive here and find the solution.

If the question is of bad quality, then we should have marked it for deletion at first place and if we missed doing so, then maybe the right time is now that you are in the spring clean-up mood.

Comment: Fair point made FFrewin.

Comment: If the question is particularly good, I'd even recommend putting a bounty on it.

Comment: Agreed with @FFrewin

Comment: Agreed with @FFrewin

Comment: Note that there are badges for answering old questions. Let's all become Necromancers!