# What is the protocol around educating a JSE userss about accepting answers and replying to answers?

Tags: discussion

Is there a particular protocol or etiquette with SE around giving users, particularly new users, a prompt, a nudge or an understanding the benefits of accepting answers, engaging with  and following up on their questions?

I am thinking that if we can help new JSE users understand the benefits of accepting answers or at least coming back to provide an update on the final outcome then that should increase the overall quality of JSE and the people doing the answering are going to be more inclined to offer assistance.

There are very few answers in the last few pages showing an Accepted answer whereas looking in each of them many show that a provided answer has resolved or assisted the person while others have absolutely no reply at all.

I can't say I have accepted answers in 100% of my questions, but I do review them from time to time to see if I can add anything further, and some are in state where the answer(s) provided hasn't actually helped resolve the question but there is good information so I might up-vote the answer(s) but then the question remains 'open'. Maybe there needs to be another state of 'Closed' for a question that is resolved but not due to any answers provided and thus can't be Accepted.

For newer users of JSE, particularly people who think it is like other Forum or Comment sections, who don't understand that SE is built on a reputation model and accepting and engaging with the answers is of benefit to them.

For example I am more selective in the questions I answer, in that I will review the users previous questions asked and check if they accepted answers, engaged with follow up comments and came back and provided the final resolution. If they ask questions and there is little or no follow up or accepted answers when clearly they resolved the question then I don't invest any, or at least, substantial time on their new question. Harsh maybe, but I would rather invest in the people who understand and contribute in the spirit JSE.

So back to the question, how can we help educate the newer users to understand that engaging and accepting with the answers provided will help their own reputation and encouraging others to invest their time in answering their question?

These are similarly related questions that have been suggested as I typed this answer that I think have some relevance;

[What do we do with questions that are old and have no answers](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-old-and-have-no-answers)

[Old questions are still not marked as solved - What should be the action here?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/old-questions-are-still-not-marked-as-solved-what-should-be-the-action-here)

[Why are there so Many First Questions Answered but Never Accepted?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/why-are-there-so-many-first-questions-answered-but-never-accepted)